# Access properties of container view's superview

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicontainerview

What I want to achieve:

when the user presses a button in the view controller in the container view I want it to be able to access and change a property of the super view of which the container view is a subview in.

Is this possible? I have seen a lot of questions about the super view being able to access the subview's properties but I would really like for the container view to be able to access the superview's property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property `parentViewController` as `self.parentViewController` and access all the properties you want.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you are trying to do is wrong from architectural point of view. When a parent has an access to child is ok, when child has an access to parent — not ok. You break a modular structure of your app. You cannot reuse your views after that.